# Gradle search dependency in repository from maven pom.xml

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android library dependency which I pull in from my own Maven repository (Artifactory based):

```
compile "com.jmolsmobile.mylibrary:mylibrary:1.0.4"
```

This dependency depends on another library, which is located in another Maven repository with a custom URL:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/' } 
}
```

What I want to do is to include my Android library in another project, without having to add the repository URL explicitly to my Gradle files, but rather have my project inherit the repository URL via the Maven `pom.xml`.

But Gradle does not search in the custom repository URL:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.splunk.mint:mint:4.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.jar
         http://10.0.190.250:8081/artifactory/android-snapshot-local/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.pom
         http://10.0.190.250:8081/artifactory/android-snapshot-local/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android-SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android-SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android-SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android-SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/splunk/mint/mint/4.2.1/mint-4.2.1.jar
```

Even though the repository is explicitly defined in my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jmolsmobile.mylibrary</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>splunk</id>
            <url>https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk.mint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mint</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any ideas why this is going wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am in the same boat.

Comment: Nope unfortunately not

Comment: So, 2 years later, any solution?